# Diff between importing Keras as "from tensorflow.python import keras" vs "from tensorflow import keras"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I understand that tensorflow version 2.x are eager execution enabled. However, I see a big performance and speed difference if I import Keras from tensorflow via `tensorflow.python.keras` vs `tensorflow.keras`. I am using tensorflow version 2.3.1.

I can train my model much faster in 50 epochs reaching 100% accuracy by importing Keras via `python.keras`, whereas my model never gets 100% accuracy with test data even with 100 epochs if I import Keras as `tensorflow.keras`.

Fast execution (also used in kaggle tutorials)

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

Slow Execution:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

My model details and results are here: https://github.com/skhalil/DataScience/blob/master/Projects/AdidasVsNike/WithKeras.ipynb

Comment: As par as i know, `tensorflow.python.keras` directly imports the module from the source code which in intended for development rather than public use, while `tensorflow.keras` uses the API generated by `tensorflow` based on the version installed on your machine. So, it is suggested not to use anything with `tf.python.*`. Hope this help you.